# This script whiptail not working correctly

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
variabile = $(whiptail --title "EXALL" --menu "Inserisci il tipo di comando da eseguire" 25 78 16 \
"Apri" "per aprire un programma in background" \
"Esegui" "per aprire un programma in background" \
"Aprire" "per aprire un file" \
"Eseguire" "per eseguire un file" \
"Esci" "Esci dal programma" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

case $variabile in
    "Esci")   
$(echo whiptail --inputbox "What is your favorite Color?" 8 78 Blue --title "Example Dialog" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
    ;;
  esac
```

When I select the option "Esci" it doesn't open the inputbox dialog, but the script ends.
Thank you

Comment: Assignments in the shell can't have spaces around `=`.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

To make it works it should be: (and use ShellCheck is a good advise!)

```
#!/bin/bash
variabile="$(whiptail --title 'EXALL' --menu 'Inserisci il tipo di comando da eseguire' 25 78 16 \
'Apri' 'per aprire un programma in background' \
'Esegui' 'per aprire un programma in background' \
'Aprire' 'per aprire un file' \
'Eseguire' 'per eseguire un file' \
'Esci' 'Esci dal programma' 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)"

case $variabile in
    "Esci")   
echo whiptail --inputbox "What is your favorite Color?" 8 78 Blue --title "Example Dialog" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
;;
esac
```

Comment: And a good habit would be to have `# author: you` `# mail: you(at)you(dot)edu` `#License: something GNU ;-)`